# Python Facebook graph API post URL with preview

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, preview

I am trying to post a link on my facebook wall using Graph API. When I manually put URL in "Write Something" textbox, it shows a preview for URL and post it as well.
 [image: Manual Post on FB wall]

I tried posting same URL via graph api

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
graph.put_wall_post("http://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/world/7-year-old-writes-to-google-for-job-ceo-sundar-pichai-replies/3526608.html")
```

But it post the link as text. I am using [Facebook-SDK](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) for accessing Facebook graph APIs.

How can I achieve same from Graph API?

Comment: What is graph.put_wall_post?

Comment: @WizKid, I updated the question.

Comment: We still have no idea what put_wall_post does

Comment: put_wall_post is function provided in Facebook API to write on facebook wall. I am way, graph get the access to wall page and function write in textbox used for sharing thoughts.

Comment: No Facebook API are HTTP requests. put_wall_post is part of some SDK you are using. Which you have never told us

Comment: @WizKid, sorry I forgot to mention, I am using Facebook-sdk from https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.

Comment: If you don't know what the SDK does you should ask the people that wrote it

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I followed your suggestion and finally I figured out my self after going through the source code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sharing a URL, you will want to use the attachment parameter so that a thumbnail preview appears in the post.
You have to add it in the following way as the API reference suggests:

```
import facebook
def main():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_user_access_token', version='2.8')
    #if version 2.8 show error use 2.6
    attachment =  {
        'name': 'Link name'
        'link': 'https://www.example.com/',
        'caption': 'Check out this example',
        'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
        'picture': 'https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
    }

    graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment, profile_id='your_page_id')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you leave the profile_id blank, it will default to your profile. In the attachment dictionary, you can leave the extra fields that you don't need.

Comment: Yes I used the same and resolved the issue on 21 Feb